# Oracle 19c doesnt support "AUTHENTICATION_TYPE" parameter in the SYS_CONTEXT function. What's the alternative now?

Tags: oracle19c

Oracle 19c doesn't support `AUTHENTICATION_TYPE` parameter in the SYS_CONTEXT function. What's the alternative now?

For example:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATION_TYPE') FROM DUAL;
```

This would show result in previous versions like, 12c R2 etc. but, throwing the below error in 19c.

> ORA-02003: invalid USERENV parameter

Answer (score 0):

`AUTHENTICATION_TYPE` was valid in Oracle 10.2 (2005). From Oracle 11g onwards, you can use `AUTHENTICATION_METHOD` instead. The return values are slightly different, but the functionality is basically the same. Please check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html) for details.